# HTTP Requests from Android app to SQL Server issue

Tags: java, android, sql-server, okhttp

I am currently working on my Android app. To receive data, that is required to run my app, I made a rest API for my app. I used the newest version of Okhttp3. Here's the classes and methods I created:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.test3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        //displayQuote();
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> receiveData());
    }
    public void init(){
        if (! Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
        }
    }

    public void receiveData() {
        TextView text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = findViewById(R.id.text2);

        APIManager apiManager = new APIManager();
        String url = "http://ip_address:1433/test";

        apiManager.fetchData(url, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Błąd pobierania danych", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    String responseData = response.body().string();

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseData);
                        String jsonResponse = json.optString("response");

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
                        if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                            String test = jsonObject.optString("test");

                            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                text1.setText(id);
                                text2.setText(test);
                            });
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Brak danych", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Błąd przetwarzania danych JSON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                    }
                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Błąd pobierania danych", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

APIManager:

```
package com.example.test3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import okhttp3.*;
import java.io.IOException;


public class APIManager {
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void fetchData(String url, final okhttp3.Callback callback){
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                callback.onFailure(call, e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    String responseData = response.body().string();
                    callback.onResponse(call, response);
                } else {
                    callback.onFailure(call, new IOException("Request failed: "+ response));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TestTable:

```
package com.example.test3;

public class TestTable {
    private int id;
    private String test;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

As you can notice, my code is simply a testfield, I tried some other solutions, but the solution I want to proceed seems to be the best.

I also created a procedure for my database, that is meant to receive HTTP requests from REST API from my app and send him a response. Here's the query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListenAndSendRequest]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(200) = 'http://ip_address:1433/test'
    
    DECLARE @requestBody NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @response NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @httpStatus INT
    DECLARE @data TABLE (id INT, test NVARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @data (id, test)
    SELECT id, test FROM test_table

    SET @requestBody = (
        SELECT id, test
        FROM @data
        FOR JSON PATH
    )

    DECLARE @httpObj INT
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @httpObj OUT

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObj, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false'

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
    
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObj, 'send', NULL, @requestBody

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObj, 'responseText', @response OUTPUT

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObj, 'status', @httpStatus OUTPUT

    PRINT 'Response: ' + @response
    PRINT 'HTTP Status: ' + CAST(@httpStatus AS NVARCHAR(10))

    EXEC sp_OADestroy @httpObj
END
```

I will be honest, I can't really say if this procedure listens to the HTTP requests. I am still learning.

There are no crashes occurred, whenever I run the app. But when I click the button, that is meant to display the data from my database, my logcat displays a warning. Here's the warning I am talking about:

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://ip_address:1433/...

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
```

It's  also worth to mention, that I run my app on physical device.

Every suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't even think about using the ancient `sp_OA` procedures, they are buggy and full of issues. Instead use Python, Java or C# or Powershell to get the data from SQL Server and send it. The table variable seems unnecessary, you can just do `SELECT (SELECT id, test FROM test_table FOR JSON PATH)`

Comment: You can't "call" sql server procedures as if it were a rest api, you have to go through the old boring jdbc. What you should do is to create an API server between your app and sql server, this server can act as API endpoint, and then call your database by jdbc from the API server and return json as results

Comment: _I will be honest, I can't really say if this procedure listens to the HTTP requests._ It doesn't. It's trying to send a POST request to the web server listening at ip_address:1433 except that most likely SQL Server is listening on that port and doesn't understand nor care for HTTP requests.